# PL/SQL To create a Procedure to get the average salary

Tags: plsql

Hello I am new in PL/SQL and I have to perform a query to " get the average salary of instructors for branch “CSE” ".

So far I have done this much.

```
Create or Replace procedure Avg_Salary 
Is
avg_salary number := 0;
Begin
select salary into avg_salary from Ins_Table where branch="CSE" ;
End
```

But I don't know how to count the number of records fetched or how to add the salaries of each row.
Can someone help me out there?

Comment: Use `AVG function` to get Average. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-jan/o13sql-1886636.html

Comment: Thanks I am really new in this that's why I didn't get the obvious solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just for you reference:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Avg_Salary
IS
   avg_salary   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   SELECT AVG (salary)
     INTO avg_salary
     FROM Ins_Table
    WHERE branch = 'CSE';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('No Data');
END;
```

Note that its good to have `exception` block at the end to trace any issue in your code.